# Angular - Provide global service for lazyloading modules

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-modules

So, I've 3 modules in my Angular app.

```
// main module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

// lazy loading module
@NgModule({
})
export class ClinicModule { }

// lazy loading module
@NgModule({  
})
export class PatientModule { }
```

we know, for lazyloading behavior purposes, I cant import **ClinicModule** and **PatientModule** in my **AppModule**.

But, there is a service inside of ClinicModule called **PatientGroupService**.

I use this service in ClinicModule for CRUD operations and in PatientModule to bring the PatientGroup List.

So, I need it in both module, the only way, I found, to get only one instance of PatientGroupService without import ClinicModule in AppModule was provide PatientGroupService directly on AppModule, like this

```
// main module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers :[PatientGroupService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You may noticed, it is not a "global service", only a service used for 2 non main modules.

It works, but I wanna know:

- Is this the "correct way" to achieve my goal?
- Is there another/better way to do that?

Comment: why not provide this service in `ClinicModule` and `PatientModule` only?

Comment: First of all, Thanks for reply Maximus !! ..

At this particular case, there is no problem, I dont need only one instance( In fact, It would make it modules more auto sufficient). 
But, Should not I try to keep only one instance whenever I can?  It would have better performance?

Asides, if I realy need only one instance, is this aproach acceptable?

Comment: there's almost no difference between one and two instances) so I would go with two instances since it provides encapsulation - you don't really need an application wide visibility. But if you really need only once instance, you should provide the service in AppModule only

Comment: Thanks Max !! .. You have made my day!!

Comment: you're welcome buddy, good luck!

Comment: And if you rly need a single instance of the service, you can create an instance at the root module and share this instance between lazy-loaded modules. @see https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-di-tree.html

Comment: Yes VuuRWerK, that is what I did using the 'forRoot()' Pattern!!! Thanks again!